# Role of the map function between Angular 4 and Angular 5

Tags: angular

Here is a code i was used to write in Angular 4:

Service:

```
import {Inject, Injectable} from '@angular/core'
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class Service1 {
    constructor(private http:Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string) { } 

    loadData() {
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'api/Listes/').map( res => res.json());
    }
    ...
```

Component:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import {Service1} from "../../services/service1.service";
    import {Liste} from "../../models/Liste";
    ...
    export class Composant1Component {
        private donnees:Liste[]

        constructor(private service1:Service1) { }

        ngOnInit()
        {
            this.service1.loadData().subscribe(res => { this.donnees = res });
        }
    }
```

And now, look at the differences in Angular 5:

Service:

```
 import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
 ...
 @Injectable()
 export class Service1
 {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string) {  }

    loadData() 
    {
       return this.http.get<Liste[]>(this.baseUrl + 'api/Lists/');
    }
```

Component:

```
   export class Composant1Component 
   {
        private donnees:Liste[];

        constructor(private service1:Service1) { }

        ngOnInit()
        {
            this.service1.loadData().subscribe(res => { this.donnees = res });
        }
   ...
```

I do not understand what was exactly the role of map() function before. And why this call is not necessary in Angular 5 ? HttpClient and Http are both returning an Observable, isn't it ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm sure there is no difference in its behavior between 4 and 5. The problem has to be with the URL you're calling (`this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'api/Listes/')`) Did you check the browser console for errors?

Comment: 1. The `map` was to take the response and extract the JSON, hence `res.json()`. 2. It's not necessary now because `HttpClient`, unlike `Http`, extracts the JSON by default; see https://angular.io/guide/http. They both return observables, yes, but *of different things by default*. I wrote a blog article when the new client was introduced that may be of use: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Jul/15/angular-http-client.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular, in its fourth version, integrates a new API for HTTP calls, called `HttpClient`.

The old version was called `Http`.

In the old API, you had to convert your answer with an internal function called `json()`, that was used to `map` the response to a readable object. This is why you used map.

In the new API, they saw that most of the time, only the response was returned. So they decided to get rid of the old `json` call, and return directly the content of the response. But don't worry, you still can see other parts of the requests you make. It's just not the default behavior anymore.

Comment: Thanks but what happens if my service is not returning json, but a raw binary file for example ?

Comment: In this case, you can **[take a look at the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)**, they explain all you need to know about reading the full response !